# Localization of the TraceSource for ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, localization, trace

If I define the `TraceSource` as such:

```
private static TraceSource traceSource = new TraceSource("MyTrace");
```

and then post messages from the code:

```
traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 1, "My message");
```

when my `web.config` has the following:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sources >
      <source name="MyTrace" switchName="Myswitch" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="textWriterListener" traceOutputOptions="DateTime"
              type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData="Log\My_diagnostic.log">
          </add>
          <remove name="Default" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="Myswitch" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

what I'd get in the `My_diagnostic.log` trace file is this:

```
MyTrace Information: 1 : My message
    DateTime=2013-03-05T04:45:54.9240441Z
```

The IIS server that this script runs on has English-US code page configured by default.

My question is, will the output in the `My_diagnostic.log` trace file be the same if the code page is set to any language other than English? And also will the date/time format be the same as I quoted above?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is no magic translation of your constant text that your put in `Trace` call.

It is unusual to localize trace messages as resulting logs are expected to be used by original developers and not the user. On other hand you can put localized messages if you want to.

The date format is ISO8601 in UTC time zone, so it will not change irrespective of user's or server's culture or time zone.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed to know. My main concern was the date/time format and the word `Information` in my example. And no, I don't need it localized. I was just confirming...